# Improving on chains of if/else statements

Tags: c++

Given the discussion [here](http://blog.demofox.org/2016/10/14/a-data-point-for-msvc-vs-clang-code-generation/), which is roughly about getting the compiler to compute if/else at compile time...

```
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename U, typename ... T>
bool one_of(U&& u, T && ... t)
{
  bool match = false;
  (void)std::initializer_list<bool>{ (match = match || u == t)... };
  return match;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  return one_of(argc, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

I've been working in older C++ land for quite a while and am not as clued in on modern C++ as I'd like to be, so...

Is there a way to do the above with, for example, an array of strings that is known at compile time?  I'd greatly prefer that it avoid loops.  The above works fairly well for int/float types and generates 3 to 5 instructions in x86_64 for the example above.

In it's most simple form, I guess this question is about how to turn an array into a list of arguments for a templated function.

Edit: at the request of krzaq

What I'd like to see if the above but instead of `one_of( argc, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )`  I'd like to have `one_of( argc, array_of_compiletime_ints )` and have it boiled down to similar code and have it work for things other than char/short/int/float/double.

If you look at any of the godbolt links, you'll see that it compiles down to very little code.

Comment: I'm still not 100% what you wanted, though, is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Y5ElOpz3X7mH0FXJ) the right direction? (can't post compiler explorer links, boost.hana is absent there :( But static asserts should assuage your fears)

Comment: @krzaq That's kinda what I want.  Though I have something of an allergy to boost.  I'll explore it.  I've been playing around with things here: https://godbolt.org/g/YOC9t1 if you're interested.  Just move the comments around and change the compiler and compiler switches as you see fit.

Comment: [Hana can be used without Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html). I'll dive into your examples now.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to leverage the Turing completeness of the template system has been a thing since the early 90s :):)

But compilers usually courteously but adamantly, and wisely so, refuse to go too deep into template computation because it would imply extensive compile time spent extremely slowly evaluating something that could so easily be expressed as a way faster runtime computation :)

Comment: Take a look at this video by the gentleman that inspired the blog post I quoted.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBkNBP00wJE -- I find it inspiring...

Answer (score 0):

The example in the question (taken from the linked blog post) is somewhat misleading - it creates a false impression that new features of C++11 allow achieving wonderful results, whereas it only demonstrates how good modern compilers are at optimizing code. Given that the input data is known at compile time even a loop can be optimized to the same effect.

Here is the requested `one_of( argc, array_of_compiletime_ints )` function, though not without a loop:

```
template<typename U, typename T, int N>
bool one_of(U&& u, T (&a)[N])
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
      if (a[i] == u)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  return one_of(argc, a);
}
```

clang 3.9.0 compiles this at optimization level -O3 into:

```
main:                                   # @main
        dec     edi
        cmp     edi, 5
        sbb     eax, eax
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

Check it [at godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/DPKZ4F).

Comment: You make a good point.  due to this point, I started playing around more with godbolt and have this https://godbolt.org/g/YOC9t1 -- If you're interested.

Comment: @JimR Yes, that's normal. I think that you don't fully understand how the `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` case got optimized so well. It's because checking that an unsigned integer value `n` belongs to the set `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` is equivalent to the test `n-1<5`. That optimization doesn't apply for a non-consecutive set of value (i.e. `{1, 3, 6, 7, 9}` cannot be optimized in such a way). Similarly that optimization cannot be applied to a set of strings.

Comment: I understand how it works, that 1,2,3,4,5 being a sequence made it almost optimal for optimization.  However...  I'm interested in doing it with other things as well like strings, doubles and floats.  I'm also interested in the ability to unroll loops over small arrays (known at compile time) and in particular having the code generated be small.  I have a use case in mind and this would be in the inner loop.